# Edit Xcode color scheme for line number background

Tags: xcode, color-scheme

Anyone knows how to change the line number background color in Xcode, referring to the area in the red box below? Access the setting by:

> Xcode -> Preferences... -> Fonts & Colors

I read through the `.dvtcolortheme` file but haven't found any hint.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that the line number/gutter area is given its background colour automatically based on what the background of the editor is. This can be seen by changing the editor's background colour to white or black, and it chooses both a darker colour for white, and a lighter colour for black.

Comment: I agree the color is generated automatically based on the background color. But changing the color of an existing scheme has no effect. Maybe we can't do more on it now and thank you for the reply.

Comment: @WangYudong See my answer for editing the line number background color on custom schemes.

Comment: You are correct, it adjusts automatically. Xcode needs to be restarted for changes to take effect though. @doug-smith

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the background of the line colors by going opening the color scheme in a text editor and changing the values for the property `DVTMarkupTextInlineCodeColor`

[image]

These are decimal RGB color values so in this example I have set the background to white with an opacity level of `0.7`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Beau. However I didn't find a key named `DVTMarkupTextInlineCodeColor`in any of my color scheme files. Although I can add those two lines into the color scheme file, but it didn't make any difference. Created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/wyudong/5daaa8dfe8da7182795e).

Answer (score 0):

It could be fixed with Xcode restart